# NoClassDefFoundError: IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror

I can't figure out what would cause this in my code, but here is the error I'm getting.  I use Intellij 12, so I'm guessing that this has to be related.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **IDEA**
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: IDEA
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates you are trying to run a class named "IDEA". Is that the name of your class? Check your run configuration (*Run > Edit Configurations*). Make sure the "Main class" field has the fully qualified name of the class that has the `main` method. You can just also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> in the editor when your class with the `main`method open.

If you still have issues, can you provide a code sample of your main class and a screen shot of the run/debug configuration you are using to try to run it.

Comment: I am facing this similar issue. There is no class with this name. Why a fictitious class with this name is being invoked, I can't understand